# Generate YML file from Jenkinsfile

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm learning Jenkinsfile and I'm trying to generate a YML file from the variables but it dosn't work properly.

```
pipeline {
agent any
parameters{
    choice(
        choices: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'], 
        name: 'select_parameter'
    )
    string(
        defaultValue: 'string', 
        name: 'STRING_PARAMETER', 
        trim: true
    )
        def amap = ['select_parameter': ${params.select_parameter}]
        writeYaml file: 'datas.yaml', data: amap
        def read = readYaml file: 'datas.yaml'
        assert read.choice == ${params.select_parameter}
}

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Test prueba'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can someone help me? I've read this documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below and put it in a script block.

```
def filename = 'datas.yaml'
def data = readYaml file: filename

// Change something in the file
data.image.tag = applicationVersion

sh "rm $filename"
writeYaml file: filename, data: data
```